# BigQuery: transforming repeated records into columns

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, nosql

My team decided to store Firebase events in BigQuery using repeated record schema:

[image: BigQuery table schema]

The table will look something like this:

```
event_name      | event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
element_clicked |       element_id |                       button-1
                |           result |                             ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
element_clicked |       element_id |                       image-23
--------------------------------------------------------------------
screen_openend  |        screen_id |                  launch_screen
```

Is there a way that will allow me to transform repeated records into the columns, so the new table looks like this:

```
event_name      | element_id | result |     screen_id
-----------------------------------------------------
element_clicked |  button-1  |     ok |          NULL 
-----------------------------------------------------
screen_opened   |       NULL |   NULL | launch_screen 
-----------------------------------------------------
element_clicked |  image-34  |   NULL |          NULL
```

*Alternatively: is there any other easy way that will allow me to query e.g. "events with name element_clicked and element_id = button-1 or events with name screen_opened and screen_id = launch_screen"?*

I started to experiment with UNNEST function, but I don't think it will behave correctly when event_params list differs from row to row:

```
SELECT 
   event_name,
   ELEMENT_ID.value.string_value AS element_id,
   RESULT.value.string_value AS result,
   SCREEN_ID.value.string_value AS screen_id
FROM my_table, UNNEST(event_params) AS ELEMENT_ID, UNNEST(event_params) AS RESULT, UNNEST(event_params) AS SCREEN_ID
WHEN ELEMENT_ID.key = 'element_id' AND RESULT.key = 'result' AND SCREEN_ID.key = 'screen_id'
```

Comment: looks good! thanks